# Making an interactive blender tool to pick vertex pairs from two seperate objects

Tags: python, 3d, blender

I want to build a tool which can let me open two objects in blender and associate every vertex in one object to another vertex in the other objects forming vertex pairs and later write the related indices to a file.

Is there any way i can do this with blender python scripting?

Answer (score 1):

You may find the [MultiEdit addon](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?339369-MultiEdit-ALPHA-2%28Major-Update%29-Multiple-Objects-Editing) of interest. This addon "merges" multiple meshes to allow editing them at the same time and then replaces the object meshes when you finish.

You may also find [CGCookies retopoflow](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/retopoflow/) inspirational as well. You can view the retopoflow code on [github](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow). I haven't looked through the code but it appears they use the [bgl module](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bgl.html) to draw custom controls over the mesh. In a similar fashion you could read [`object.data.mesh.vertices`](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Mesh.html#bpy.types.Mesh.vertices) and draw points over both objects that the user could pair up.